# Is there an Outlook-like Flagging feature in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010

Is there an Outlook-like Flagging feature in SharePoint 2010?

thx!
-saumil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use SharePoint's social tagging capability (tags are usually person specific). So the tag would be "Flagged". Implementation wise there are any number of approaches (i.e. using the ribbon).

Comment: Excellent answer! It did not click to me to use Tags as flags!

Answer (score 1):

Not out the box, no.

You could probably implement something similar, by creating a custom column in your list of type "Yes/No" called "Flagged" or something similar.

You could also replicate the flag in Outlook probably (selecting a time-scale from a drop-down box sets the "due date" for a task [for example] to the timescale selected by the flag), but this will almost certainly require custom development.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up work flows though, which sync with Outlook and mean you can set due by dates for the flow, which is out of the box. This will be in Outlook for flagging mind, not in SP itself but still has the desired effect if done properly.